# Uploading Images with RAW JSON POST request ? DRF - Django Rest Framework

Tags: json, django-rest-framework, request, httprequest

How do I upload images with raw json requests. Using Django REST as the backend.

Example :

```
{ 
   'name':'RK Villa',
   'address':'Addres goes here'
   'images':[{'name':'Front','image':'local/url'},{'name':'Front','image':'local/url'}]
}
```

The file is not getting attached. I am trying to send this to Django rest framework.

Answer (score 0):

To upload image or file you need to use html `<form></form>` element. Then you grasp that file with JavaScript `FormData`. And finally send this `FormData` object to backend via ajax. Follow the below example.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" id="book_name">
    <input type="file" id="book_image">
    <button type="submit" id="submit_btn">Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
    $('#submit_btn').click(function(){
        var book_name = $('#book_name').val();
        var book_image = $('#book_image')[0].files[0];

        //I need to create a FormData object
        var fd = new FormData();

        fd.append('backend_book_name', book_name);
        fd.append('backend_book_image', book_image);

        //'backend_book_name' & 'backend_book_image' must be same to your drf model field name

        $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url: 'http://localhost:8000/YOUR_URL',
            data: fd,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function(res){
                console.log(res);
            }
        });
    });  
</script>
```

Don't forget to set the attribute 'enctype = multipart/form-data'  in your HTML form.